# How to add a new graph to an existing one?

Tags: cytoscape

How can I add a new graph to an existing one in Cytoscape? Suppose that I have loaded a graph, but later I have some new data (new points, new connections) and I want to expand the existing graph. How can I do it in Cytoscape?

I am new to Cytoscape and have been using the point-and-click approach. I hope I don't have to write code to solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of different ways to do it -- neither of which involve programming.  First, you can import the new data into a separate graph and then use the Merge Networks function to merge your existing network with the new data.

Second, you could write a little command script with lines like "network add node ..." and "network add edge ...".  The syntax for these commands can be found by bringing up the command line (look in the lower left corner) and type "help network add node" and "help network add edge".